JSON mapping with obfuscated property names
I'm building a replacement server for the 2013 Android-based PlayJam GameStick micro console and implemented the server-side leaderboard APIs.
One game crashes when retrieving the leaderboard data, the unity-based "Stop the birds".
I extracted the (presumably C#/unity script) Assembly-CSharp.dll file and loaded it into ILspy and dnSpy.
The game uses LitJson to automatically map JSON responses onto objects, and I suspect something fails there, leading to a null pointer exception.
Both ILspy and dnSpy only show obfuscated property names like B and A inside the classes that get JSON data mapped onto:
    private class BodyElement
    {
        public bool B; //should be "success"

        public string A;

        public string Y;

        public LeaderboardDataItem[] V; //should be named "leaderBoard"
    }

    public LeaderboardData(string d)
    {
        o = LitJson.JsonMapper.ToObject<LeaderboardDataJson>(d);
    }

How can LitJson map the correct properties when the property names are not available?
